# How can I upload Telerik Test Studio test results to TestLink

Tags: testlink, telerik

I would like to integrate Telerik Test Studio with TestLink.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any built in support for TestLink ([source](http://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/features/integration/bug-tracking/Configuration)). You could integrate it manually through VB or C# code ([coded step](http://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/advanced-topics/coded-steps/coded-step)) where when a test fails, it does whatever you want it to (Ex., Upload the test result via an API POST method). I would try the TestLink forums to get help with that if it's a route you want to explore.

Other than that, copy+paste!